# Wordpress: How to get reference for this category

Tags: wordpress

I'm editing the file named `category.php` under a certain theme package. I want to display the name of the category and get the number of posts that are under the category.

How can I reference `this` category?

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$category = get_the_category(); 
echo $category[0]->cat_name;
?>
```

Return the first category found.

More detail here : http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_category

Comment: I want a reference to the current category not the first one.